# How to autostart jobs when using zsh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, background, zsh

I switched to zsh for my daily usage recently. One problem that I come across is that how I can autostart some background command line executable(for example, `fetchmail -d 1800`). When I add the line into `~/.zprofile` or `~/.zshrc`, everything goes fine until I open another zsh process instance(in fact, I am using `tmux` so it happens frequently), fetchmail complains that

```
  fetchmail: can't accept options while a background fetchmail is running.
```

I thought that `~/.zprofile` might only be executed once, but It seems that I was wrong. So how can I handle it properly?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Better than original idea (from comment below):

```
ps -C fetchmail >/dev/null || fetchmail -d 1800
```

---

**Fixed original idea:**

How about checking if there is process in background already running and running `fetchmail` only if it isn't:

```
[ -z `ps aux | grep "fetchmail" | grep -v "grep"` ] && fetchmail -d 1800
```

Comment: There is `ps -C fetchmail`, don’t use `grep`. Also note that you have wrong position of `-z` argument (but with `ps -C` you don’t need `[ -z` at all: `ps -C fetchmail >/dev/null || fetchmail -d 1800`).

Comment: It works! BTW, I figure out that it is better to put this line into `~/.profile` since X window manager will always read it *once* during startup. There is still a need to check since when someone logout and relogin, the `~/.profile` is sourced one more(although generally the error message would be redirected into `~/.xsession-errors` other than stdout).

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to start it in zsh configuration file? All or almost all of window managers and desktop environments support running commands at startup. For example, when using fluxbox you can just add this startup line into `$HOME/.fluxbox/startup`.

Note: `.zprofile` is read each time somebody starts a login shell. `.zshrc` is read each time somebody starts interactive shell. `.zshenv` is read each time somebody starts a shell (no matter which). (Unless explicitly turned off by command-line arguments.) There is really no configuration file which is read only once.

Comment: Actually I know there is an alternative that I can configure it in the X Window Manager, but it's not a general solution. What I am surprising is that when I write `export PATH=$PATH:/my/extra/path` in .zprofile, when I start a new zsh instance, no more `/my/extra/path` is appended into `PATH`; but writtern in .zshrc, the self-customed path is always appended to the PATH variable. I don't know why.

Comment: @HongxuChen Some terminal emulators are known to always launch login shell by default. Other do not launch login shells unless configured/requested from command-line. Thus `.zshrc` is the best place to modify path, it is always used when shell is interactive. Though to make `$PATH` cleaner I always add some condition that first checks that needed path is not already in `$PATH` and only then adds it.